# getting a files contents with CURL PHP?

Tags: php, file, curl

The content will not load from the file, here is my curl code,

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
// GET CONTENTS OF HASHES.TXT
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://xxx.com/api/x.txt');
// SUCCESSFULY OPENED HASHES.TXT
$file = curl_exec($curl);
echo $file; // RETURNS NOTHING
echo curl_error($curl); // COULDN'T CONNECT TO HOST
echo curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // 0
```

The curl is working as I have previously opened other webpages further up the script,

Thanks

Comment: You're code should work, the problem is the 'couldn't connect to host'. Can you ping the host from where your code is being executed?

Comment: It is a file on my own server I can open it using `file_get_contents('x.txt')` just fine! Just strange how curl can't?!

Comment: can you curl anything on your server? For example from a simple php script crul a text file in the web root?

Answer (score 1):

In order to grab response into the variable you should use:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

before doing exec.

Comment: I have that further up the code, probably should have included it in!