# how get php content

Tags: php, get, include, fopen, file-get-contents

how can i get php file contents with php or js file from other server
with allow_url_fopen ON  ?
i try this first - ITS WORK but from my server !

```
<?php
    $url = "index.php";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
 echo $json;
echo 1;
?>
```

i its not work

```
    <?php
    $url = "http://mysite.com/index.php";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
 echo $json;
echo 1;
?>
```

anyone know how get file content with allow_url_fopen from other server?
or other user from my server?
or get variable from that file?

Comment: What's the error you are getting ?

Comment: If you expect to get the **PHP source** from another server via HTTP: no. Hopefully no. Good god, no!

Comment: so why i can get php source from my server?

Comment: its not give an error its just get null content

Comment: Try it with curl ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707216/getting-a-files-contents-with-curl-php )

Comment: @masiharastooyi Are you trying to build a system that has source code across multiple servers ?

Comment: yes kevingreen ... but i just want get a variable from them

Comment: @masiharastooyi Hmm, this might be a bit more complex that what you're thinking. You can pass data across servers via HTTP using webservices. Look into SOAP or RESTful services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How a file is opened depends on the stream wrapper, which depends on the full URL.

`file_get_contents('index.php')` defaults to the local file system wrapper, i.e. it opens the file directly from the hard disk and reads its contents.

`file_get_contents('http://example.com/index.php')` uses the HTTP stream wrapper. You cannot access the file on the hard disk of another server directly (*hopefully* you can't). Opening `http://example.com/index.php` is the same as putting that URL into your browser: it makes an HTTP request to that URL and the result is whatever the other server outputs **after processing the PHP file**, like with any regular web request.

Comment: aha so there is noway to get variable from php file with url? ha? so what allow_url_fopen ON do?

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` allows you to make that HTTP request in the first place. It does not change what the other server responds with in return.